# Check if a number has a point

Tags: php

I want to check if a number has a point or not. How to do this with PHP?

```
$numberOne = 5;
$numberTwo = 8;
$result = $numberTwo / $numberOne;

if ($result) {
    echo "No comma!";
} else {
    echo "Comma!";
}
```

Comment: If you want to check if it's a float, just use `is_float()`. Or if you want to check if its a whole number, you can do `floor($result) == $result`

Comment: Are you talking about a comma as a thousands separator, or as a decimal separator? If the latter, look at [fmod()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php) which will return a zero or a non-zero value for `fmod($result,1)` depending on whether the float has decimals or not

Comment: `5/8` gives `0.625` without any comma

Comment: Oh yes, that's true. Sorry. I mean the point. How can I check if the value has a point.

Comment: `fmod(0.625, 1)` isn't zero, so the result of `5/8` has a decimal point

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you mean how to check if $result is float or integer so this is the way

```
$numberOne = 5;
$numberTwo = 8;
$result = $numberTwo / $numberOne;
if(is_float($result)){
echo "No comma!";
}else{
echo "Comma!";
}
```

Just replace comma and no comma...

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of [arithmetic operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) mentions:

> The division operator ("`/`") returns a float value unless the two operands are integers (or strings that get converted to integers) and the numbers are evenly divisible, in which case an integer value will be returned.

If the value you want to check is the result of a division of integer numbers then the condition *"the numbers are evenly divisible"* also means 
the result of the remainder operator ("`%`") is `0` (zero).

You don't even need to compute the result of the division to know if it is an integer or a real number:

```
$numberOne = 5;
$numberTwo = 8;

if ($numberTwo % $numberOne) {
    echo "The result is not integer. Its representation has a comma.";
} else {
    echo "The result is an integer number.";
}
```

If the type of one of the numbers you want to divide is not integer then type of the result is `float`, no matter if its value is integer or not.